# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'getsState' issue while setting up redux for application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a redux application that I am currently setting up and I am getting the following error that I am not sure about. I am trying to fix it so I can start developing the application.

```
Provider.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')
    at Provider.js:20:1
    at mountMemo (react-dom.development.js:17225:1)
    at Object.useMemo (react-dom.development.js:17670:1)
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1650:1)
    at Provider (Provider.js:20:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
(anonymous) @ Provider.js:20
mountMemo @ react-dom.development.js:17225
useMemo @ react-dom.development.js:17670
useMemo @ react.development.js:1650
Provider @ Provider.js:20
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

Timer.js file

```
export default function createTimer(name) {
  return {
    name, 
    time: 0, 
    isRunning: false
  }
}
```

timersSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import Timer from './Timer'

const initialState = {
  value: []
}

export const timersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'timers',
  initialState,
  reducers: {

    addTimer: (state, action) => {
      state.value.push(new Timer(action.payload))
    },

        toggleTimer: (state, action) => {
            state.value[action.payload].isRunning = !state.value[action.payload].isRunning
        },
        
  },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { addTimer, toggleTimer } = timersSlice.actions

export default timersSlice.reducer
```

index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import { store } from './app/app';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

the issues I think is coming from how the `Provider` is being setup in the index.js file

Comment: Do you add the slice to the app store?

Comment: I dont think so... where would I add that and which slice? @Slinker009

Comment: You need to add the slice to the store like this: `
export const ApplicationStore = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    timersStore: timersSlice.reducer 
  }, 
});
`